# Delete rows from an excel file in Python based on date

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have written this code that pulls and excel file into python reorganizes the columns and tries to remove any rows where the data in that row is older than 2012.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime 

#Read the excel with the data from IHS
Coal_Exports = pd.read_excel("U:\drive\Coal Exports.xlsx")

#Rearrange the data by columns 
Coal_Exports = pd.melt(Coal_Exports, id_vars= ["Export Country", "Import Country", "Coal type", "Date Last Updated", "Unit"],var_name="Date", value_name="value")
#set the Date as the Index
Coal_Exports = Coal_Exports.set_index(keys="Date")

#Delete pre 2012 Rows

Coal_Exports = Coal_Exports[(Coal_Exports.ix[0] > "01/01/2012")]

#Send the reformatted data to excel

Coal_Exports.to_excel ("U:\drive\Formatted Coal Exports.xlsx")
print "Done"
```

My issue is deleting the rows pre 2012,

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-8eb1513ad7c2> in <module>()
     14 #Delete pre 2012 Rows
     15 #Coal_Exports = Coal_Exports.drop[(Coal_Exports.set_index(keys="Date")<('01/01/2012') )]
---> 16 Coal_Exports = Coal_Exports[(Coal_Exports.ix[0] > "01/01/2011")]
     17 
     18 

C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   1989         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   1990             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 1991             return self._getitem_array(key)
   1992         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   1993             return self._getitem_frame(key)

C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2029             # check_bool_indexer will throw exception if Series key cannot
   2030             # be reindexed to match DataFrame rows
-> 2031             key = check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)
   2032             indexer = key.nonzero()[0]
   2033             return self.take(indexer, axis=0, convert=False)

C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.pyc in check_bool_indexer(ax, key)
   1799         mask = com.isnull(result._values)
   1800         if mask.any():
-> 1801             raise IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series key provided')
   1802 
   1803         result = result.astype(bool)._values

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided
```

The dates in the excel file are of the format 31/02/2011 etc.

I think it's something to do with the format of dates in excel being different from pandas but i'm not sure, can anyone help with this?

Comment: Checking the pandas format the date is of this type '2012-01-31 00:00:00'
I have changed my code as such, but still get the same error

Comment: check the data type of Coal_Exports.ix[0] , it seems to be something different

Comment: Does this help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088921/pandas-boolean-indexing-with-unequal-series-lengths